# Are there high resolution images available for download on earthexplorer?

Tags: landsat, imagery, zoom, resolution, earth-explorer

The problem with earth explorer GeoTiff files is, if you zoom in enough, the resolution is very fuzzy.

If you want to look at your backyard, for example, that is impossible.  If you use the earth explorer summary (on the right side of their website), which is very similar to google maps, you can zoom in on any area of the country in great detail.

Can I download images of this quality on earth explorer?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can [download some scenes of high-res imagery](https://lta.cr.usgs.gov/UCDP):

> Commercial Data Purchases (CDP) Imagery
>
> The Commercial Data Purchases (CDP) Imagery Collection contains
>   imagery from several commercial vendors and is archived at the USGS
>   Earth Resources Observation & Science Center (EROS). The CDP supports
>   the Commercial Remote Sensing Space Policy (CRSSP) by providing data
>   to qualified Federal users at no cost. See the Product Info tab for
>   more details.

Also:

> EarthExplorer can be used to search, preview, and download Commercial
>   Data Purchases (CDP) Imagery. The collections are located under the
>   Commercial Data category. See the Product Info tab for data access
>   information.

Look under the right tab

[image]

By the way, you need to learn about [spatial resolution in remote sensing](http://www.edc.uri.edu/nrs/classes/NRS409/RS/Lectures/HowRemoteSensonWork.pdf)

Comment: Thanks so much.  I am in the process of downloading one.  It's taking a long time, but will update this when I get a look. :)